# How to have service that makes sure program keeps running?

Tags: bash, shell-script, services, init.d

I made a service called `thin_keep_alive_service` in `/etc/init.d`. I gave it `chmod +x` rights. The script looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          thin_keep_alive_service
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description  Keeps Thin servers running
# Description:       This service checks every 30 seconds if at least 
#                    two light weight thin web servers are alive and 
#                    restarts them all from the bundle if not.
###END INIT INFO

while true
do
    # Store an array of the pids of thin
    thin_pid_arr=($(pgrep -f thin))

    # When there are less than two Thin servers left we reboot them all
    if [ ${#thin_pid_arr[@]} -lt 2 ]; then
        cd /root_to_app && bundle exec thin -C /etc/thin/app.yml restart
    fi

    #Wait 30 seconds before checking again
    sleep 30
done
```

It does work when I run it as `service thin_keep_alive_service start`. But it does not run in the background continuously after startup, since my two servers die after a while and no new ones are rebooted.

How to make sure it runs in the background?

Comment: What OS are you using? Most recent OSs have init systems which support service monitoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Thin as a runlevel script (under /etc/init.d/thin) that will start all your servers after boot.

```
sudo thin install
```

and setup a config file for each app you want to start:

```
thin config -C /etc/thin/myapp.yml -c /var/...
```

Run thin -h to get all options.

Read the [thin documentation](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/usage/)!

Comment: You are right!  All the other answers provide great solutions, but this is the simplest one specific to this situation. I could not use the build in functionality at first because I needed Thin in two different Ruby environments. But I removed that complexity among other things to be able to use this. I forgot! Thanks a lot for the reminder.

Comment: Oh btw. This does work, but it does not guarantee that the servers keep running, right? If they die, which they sometimes do, I do need a script?

Comment: No, if the process dies, then something's severly wrong with it. It depends on your config, but one instance should stay up.

Comment: Processes can die for many reasons -- e.g. OOM and hardware fault to name just two. Depending on the context, it may or may not be desirable to restart them automatically in such cases.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. initscripts are supposed to support at least a start and a stop command, and they're supposed to exit; having an endless loop in an initscript would normally cause the boot process to hang as it calls your script.
2. I don't know what `bundle exec thin restart` is supposed to do, but since otherwise your script is fine, it's likely the problem lies there, i.e. this bit doesn't do what you think it does. You can put `set -x` in your script to make sure it does run that command when it should.

That said, if you want services that are restarted automatically, it's almost certainly much cleaner to use a process supervisor like [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/).

Ps. you can shave off a fork() by using `while sleep 30` instead of `while true; do ... sleep 30; done`. :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you should never have a loop that blocks an init script.

What I would do is create another script which is viewed as the service. That script would have the loop and it would start the service in the foreground so the loop becomes something really simple:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
    start-service ...
    sleep 30
done
```

In your init file, you reference that script with thin or whatever other mechanism that starts a service. So you just added a layer which ensures that the service keeps running.

Now, you may also want to have a way to know when the user tries to stop the server... you do not have that in your loop either. Something like this probably:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
    start-service ...

    # service properly terminated?
    if ! test -f /var/run/service-id
    then
        exit 0
    fi

    sleep 30
done
```

If the /var/run/service-id file gets deleted **before** the "start-service" software returns, then you're good. It also means that if the service crashes, the file should not get deleted automatically (obviously).

Maybe you could also use the return value of the service. In that case you could do this instead (remember that works only if the service itself blocks):

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
    if start-service ...
    then
        # service cleanly terminated
        exit 0
    fi

    sleep 30
done
```

Note that this sort of a thing will auto-restart the app, but it won't do anything to force the app. to quit. If the app. does not crash but still goes *bad* after a while (i.e. sluggish maybe) then you'd need even more heuristic to get it to stop...

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to do this. In most common linux distributions you can use `upstart` to check if a process is running and do-something if it is not. Another good option, which I'm currently using, is `systemd`.

But, if you want to use third party software take a look at monit and godrb.